# Android SQLiteOpenHelper save custom object with object variable

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm using SQLiteOpenHelper for saving data to the db in my Android app. I want to save custom object that has another custom object as variable.

Sample of the object:

```
public class Device implements Serializable {
    public String deviceId;
    public Location location;

    public Device() {
    }
}

public class Location implements Serializable {
    public double lat;
    public double lon;

    public Location() {
    }
}
```

I'm trying to save the `Device` to my db. But when I'm loading the object back from the db, the `Location` object is always `null` even when both object are implementing `Serializable` interface.

I want to keep it as simple as possible, because I'm storing just this simple object.

Comment: Could you please try to store your objects as jsons. For example: "{deviceId:43, location: {lat: 43.43522, lon: 34.5234}}". Then use gson or Jackson. Or provide your methods to convert object to jsonString and vice versa? Or you need only Serializable?

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin I can store it as json and then restore it back using Gson for example. But I'm not sure if its the best practice or not.

Comment: Yes it's one of solutions. You can store 2 columns. First is id, second is json. But you will loose possibility to for example group objects, sort objects and e.t.c through sql queries, if you will store you data in json, not directly in columns. So you need to just decide.

Comment: But of course store data is json, is better than serialization, IMHO.

Comment: I would consider using an ORM, they're built for exactly this.